# A word that means "given to frequent censorship"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, adjectives

I always assumed that the word **censorious** meant someone or something that is given to censorship. Like if you say that a community, an organization, or a person is overly-censorious, that means they frequently or unnecessarily censor content. But I just looked up the word [in my favorite dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/censorious) and found that censorious has a different meaning than what I thought:

> **censorious**
>
> 1. Addicted to censure and scolding; apt to blame or condemn; severe in making remarks on others, or on their writings or manners.
> 2. Implying or expressing censure.

So, a censorious person is not a person who is quick to censor. Too bad, because I thought that was a useful word!

Is there an actual word that means "being given to excessive censorship"?

**Example:** I might criticize a film distributor as being _____ because they often censor controversial content whenever they release a new edition of a classic film.

Comment: What's wrong with "censorious"? What in its does not correspond to what you want it to mean?

Comment: Prone to censorship could mean inclined to censor or vulnerable to being censored.

Comment: You should look in multiple dictionaries not just rely on one: "censorious" is fine. It does often mean something closer to critical but can mean prone to censoring. "Self-censoring" might apply in your example but has a narrower meaning. Censors are also often described as "draconian" but that wouldn't apply to someone censoring their own work.

Comment: Does it have to be an adjective? Would you accept a verb, say, or a noun? If so, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bowdlerize

Comment: @Tim I would prefer an adjective as it seems more convenient when describing an entity that tends to censor things. But _bowdlerize_ is a great find and definitely a valid option here! That also reminds me of the word game _Balderdash_ which I played as a kid :)

Comment: @StuartF That's a good point about checking more than one dictionary. So I just checked the two printed dictionaries and one thesaurus that I have. But none of these include a meaning for _censorious_ that means "someone who frequently censors". The two dictionaries both have pretty much the same definition that I found on Wiktionary. What is a dictionary that gives a meaning of "prone to censoring"? _Draconian_ is good, but I think it begs more explanation, since one can be draconian about things other than censorship. And as you say, _self-censoring_ has a narrower meaning.

Comment: @Xanne Perhaps I muddied the water by using the word _prone_, because you are right—it can have two meanings. I should have said "given to censorship" or "someone who frequently censors".

Comment: @fev The problem with _censorious_ is that it does not mean "a person who frequently censors things". It means "apt to blame or condemn" and so on. Some people in the comments have suggested that it may also mean "someone who frequently censors", but I can't find a dictionary which says that, and no one has provided one. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/censorious) gives the definition "severely critical; faultfinding; carping". I guess that someone who is critical of a work might also want to censor it. But being critical is not the same as taking action to censor something.

Comment: @peacetype:   But the adjective with the meaning "too ready and willing to censor (or remove material that might offend some people)" probably doesn't exist, so you may have to say something like "X would rather bowdlerize the work than risk offending sensibilities". or "The head of X Studios is a veritable Bowdler when it comes to editing out anything that is edgy or pushes boundaries."

Comment: Actually, your own word **scold**.

Comment: @YosefBaskin But, **scold** does not mean "someone who is given to excessive censorship".

Comment: @Tim Yes, I was starting to think that maybe the word I'm looking for does not exist. But there are a couple more answers coming through now, so maybe there are some viable adjectives after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjective associated with censorship is *censorial*, not *censorious*.

From the OED:

> **censorial**: Of, pertaining to, or characteristic of a censor.
> **censorious**: Addicted to censure; severely critical; faultfinding.

So you could use *overly censorial*, which definitely has been used for the meaning you want.

However, it's a somewhat uncommon word—for example, it's not in the *Cambridge Dictionary*—and people may get it confused with *censorious*. On the positive side, if people don't confuse it with *censorious*, its meaning is fairly obvious from its construction.

Comment: Wow, thank you! What probably happened is that I heard/read someone use the term _overly censorial_ long ago. And over time, that morphed in my mind and became _overly censorious_. So then I went on thinking incorrectly that censorious meant _given to censorship_. Censorial is probably the word I was looking for! _Censorial_ alone does not carry the desired connotation of _**excessive** censorship_. But you could simply add _overly_ or _excessively_ to create that connotation. Great find!

Comment: I don't think the **-ial** adjectival ending  there admits the "overly" modifier. It would be like saying "overly postprandial".

Comment: @Tim: *overly deferential, overly territorial, overly adversarial*?

Comment: Just offering a caveat as I think a yellow light appropriate. OP asked if "an *actual* word" exists, which I took to mean "in use".  While there *are*, as you say, adjectives ending in **-ial**  that mean "exhibiting, characterized by" [some trait or behavior], *here* the meaning is "Of, characteristic of, or pertaining to the censor", which doesn't admit degree.  You were correct to say the word "*has been used* for the meaning you want." But to use the word **censorial** now to mean "overly given to acting like a censor, too much the censor"  would be a resurrection of an obsolete meaning.

Comment: @Tim: It is currently being used for the exact meaning the OP wants. [See Google books.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22overly+censorial%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AB5stBilarudnlhsiWTLXjLk9gTm0R7ipg:1688566853938&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnmYjc4ff_AhVhGlkFHeaoC68QpwV6BAgBEBQ&biw=973&bih=529&dpr=2.5) I'd say that these uses are not wrong, but rather that the dictionary's definition is not broad enough. Your opinion may differ.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It has been used, though the major dictionaries haven't reinstated that meaning as the usage has been infrequent.  I think, as you said, however, its meaning should be clear enough by analogy with other -ial adjectives, though there are other adjectives with -ial endings that don't admit degree (e.g. *too sartorial, *too tonsorial).

Comment: @Tim I'm half-joking here... but you reminded me of a time when I lived in Japan around 2006. There was a fashion trend at the time for guys to wear a pouch on their hip that we called a "scissors case". It was used to carry around your wallet, keys, handkerchief, etc., but the design was originally inspired by the scissors cases that barbers wear to hold various scissors and stuff as they work. So, if I asked you back then if you liked my cool, new scissors case, maybe you could say that you don't really like it as a fashion accessory because it seems a little too tonsorial to you? :)

Comment: @peacetype  I don't perceive "tonsorial" as being on a continuum but such twists of meaning are happening all the time. I could see a lawsuit, perhaps, where party A who had represented that it had for sale a miscellaneous lot of instruments from the Victorian era, was being sued by party B, the buyer, who claimed that there was only a very small percentage of medical and scientific instruments in the lot and that barbershop scissors predominated, and  that the supposedly miscellaneous lot was "too tonsorial"  meaning "disproportionately tonsorial in its composition".

Comment: @Tim Hahahah! Yes!! I love this conversation :)

Comment: I suppose in Japan those pouches were tonsorial-sartorial.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use **expurgatious** which is derived from ***[expurgate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expurgate)*** which means

> to cleanse of something morally harmful, offensive, or erroneous
>
> ***especially : to expunge objectionable parts from before publication or presentation***
>
> *an expurgated edition of the letters*
>
> expurgation  noun
>
> expurgator  noun

I wasn't able to find expurgatious listed in any dictionary while googling, but it seems to have been coined by John Milton, the English poet and philosopher who appears to have used it in 1641.

According to John Witte Jr. in the article [Prophets, Priests, and Kings: John Milton and the Reformation of Rights and Liberties in England](https://scholarlycommons.law.emory.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1111&context=faculty-articles)  and quoting Milton from the Complete Prose Works of John Milton in reference to Milton's pronouncements on censorship Milton expressed that

> "Nothing is more sweet to man" than
> freedom of speaking and writing, he wrote in 1641. But for the free born
> people of England, all free speaking and free publication have long been
> "pinched," "girded, and straight laced" by "monkish prohibitions, and
> ***expurgatious*** indexes" kept by "some mercenary, narrow-souled, and illiterate chaplain." Censorship is silly and self-defeating for the church, Milton
> argued.

Apropos *Bowdlerize* mentioned by @Tim in comments to OP’s question, Merriam-Webster adds in the “did you know”section of the definition linked above that

> Expurgation has a long and questionable history. Perhaps history's most famous expurgator, or censor, was the English editor Thomas Bowdler, who in 1818 published the Family Shakespeare, an expurgated edition of Shakespeare's plays that omitted or changed any passages that, in Bowdler's opinion, couldn't decently be read aloud in a family. As a result, the term bowdlerize is now a synonym of expurgate.

Comment: This seems like a very good fit! But as you say, it's a derived term, and may not be found in many dictionaries. Interestingly, I was also able to find another derived term, _[expurgatorious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expurgatorious#English)_, which also cites Milton. @Tim's suggestion of _bowdlerize_ is a helpful noun, but unlike _expurgate_, it's not easy to turn _bowdlerize_ into an adjective. _Bowdleratious_? _Bowdleratorial_? At least _expurgatious/expurgatorious_ have some precedent! I think this could be a very useful term, except for its obscurity.